# How could I connect my project which is created in Python with GitHub in Visual Studio(VS) code?

Tags: python, github, pysimplegui

I just don't know the way to connect it.

I am willing to connect my project powered by PySimpleGUI module with GitHub community so that everyone could benefit from it. However, I don't have basic knowledge of how to achieve it. it'd be great if you can help me out.

Comment: You should look at GitHub's [quickstart](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/hello-world) guide.

Comment: Did you install the GitHub extension for VSCode? Did you look up how to use GitHub? What have you done so far? Nothing?

Comment: [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) is also a great tool for getting started with GitHub, especially if your not entirely comfortable with the command line interface (CLI)

Comment: GitHub extension might be helpful but never gave it a try I'll check it out thanks

Comment: Davis could you please specify full name of the proper package cuz I didn't find out any extension when looked it up.

Comment: Plus one for GitHub Desktop!  